# Get td class text with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I want to take the text of td class.

The html page

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                <img .....>
            </td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a ....></a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                TEXT I WANT TO TAKE HERE
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a ....><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The text I want to take is "TEXT I WANT TO TAKE HERE".

I tried using the xpath like below but it didnt work

```
table = browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//div[@class='table table-striped']/tbody/tr/td[5]"));
```

I got an error saying:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='table table-striped']/tbody/tr/td[5]"}
```

Is it because I have multiple classes in the selector and I have to use dot?
(I tried: 'table.table-striped' but it still didnt work)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `table = browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//table[@class='table table-striped']/tbody/tr/td[5]"));` ?

Comment: can you try `//td[@class='text-center']` and let me know

Comment: Indeed I dont know why I had div there, do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Can you add some implicit wait and check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xpath is incorrect. You have a `table` tag but, you are looking for a `div` tag. So, you just need to replace `div` with `table`.

```
table = browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//table[@class='table table-striped']/tbody/tr/td[5]"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below xpath to get the text

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='text-center']").text
```

And use the index as well to better find your row e.g.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='text-center'][3]").text
```

Comment: yes..my bad..I noticed just after commenting, so deleted that comment.

Comment: @MD. Khairul Basar , not an issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Below `xpath` to get the text `TEXT I WANT TO TAKE HERE`

```
//table//tr/td[contains(text(), 'TEXT I WANT TO TAKE HERE')]
```

**Updated Answer:** You can refer any of these below mentioned xpath to get your webelement.

```
//td[5]
```

> OR

```
//table[@class='table table-striped']//td[5]
```

> OR

```
//table[@class='table table-striped']/..//following-sibling::td[5]
```

> OR

```
//td[@class='text-center'][3]
```

Comment: I havent, but the text I want is dynamic so I dont know before hand what it contains, thanks though

Comment: This is dynamic answer. if any td contains this text. It will locate the webelement. you can also use indexing after end of the xpath. if there are multiple matches are available for the same xpath.

Comment: Yeah what am saying is it doesnt contains this text, it just an example to show what td I wanted, regardless I made a small typo div instead of table and that was all, thanks again.

Comment: Okay, Well in this case you have to use `indexing` after end of your xpath. I have update my answer. You can refer it.

Comment: I have already marked the accepted answer, Although yours is not wrong, as I mentioned above all I had was a typo. Thank you for providing additional details.

Answer (score 1):

In your XPath expression you are looking for a div tag, but your HTML does not have that. Perhaps you are looking to the table tag:

```
table = browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//table[@class='table table-striped']/tbody/tr/td[5]"));
```

Comment: Indeed that was the mistake, though I will wait a few minutes for @MD. Khairul Basar since he noticed first and in case he doesnt post an answer, I'll accept yours